# Vagrant create alias for long machine name

Tags: vagrant

I'm on MacOS and when I start my vagrant box (vagrant up && vagrant ssh) I see a fairly long prompt

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64
```

How can I shorten it? I want something like this

```
vagrant@box
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to define a logical name for the box (see the [config.vm docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html)).

For example a minimal Vagrantfile might look like this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.hostname = "web1"
end
```

And then the shell prompt will be user@hostname, like:

```
$ vagrant ssh
vagrant@web1:~$
```

This is also handy if you ever do multiple Vagrant VMs which have different roles, like "web" versus "db" for example.